# Mock out function call to another function in same class

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I have function that calls out to another function in the same class. I'm trying to test if that method is called in my unit tests however can't find a way to mock it.

Here is an example of the method call

```
public function follow($user_id, $followsfeed, $target_user_id)
    {
        $news_feeds = $this->getNewsFeeds($user_id);

    }
```

I want to mock the method getNewsFeed and assert it is being called when I execute follow.

What is the best way to achieve this. as I can't workout how to create an internal mocked object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [partial mocks](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html#creating-partial-mocks), as example on your test class, you can do:

```
public function test_follow()
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock('App\Services\SomeService')->makePartial();
    $mock->shouldReceive('getNewsFeeds')
      ->once()
      ->with("id1","id2")
      ->andReturn($someNews);
    $mock-> follow("id1","id2"); 
}
```

You can also use the [PHPUnit test-doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html)

Hope this help